# Most efficient way to determine largest variable?

Tags: variables, batch-file

So, the question title pretty much says it all.

What is the most efficient way to go through a list of numbered variables and find out which one contains the largest number.

I have no idea of how to do this without a good 20 lines of code, so instead I'll write some example code:

```
@echo off
for /l %%i in (1,1,10) do set /p var_%%i=Insert number: 
::code here that finds out which variable is larger...
echo The largest number is... %largest_number%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%i in (1,1,10) do set /p "var_%%i=Insert number %%i: "
set largest_number=%var_1%
for /l %%i in (2,1,10) do if !var_%%i! gtr !largest_number! set largest_number=!var_%%i!
echo The largest number is... %largest_number%
```

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient solution for this problem will always be of linear time complexity, that is `O(n)`. That is because there is no real way to divide & conquer this task, as all elements must checked, demanding at least `O(n)` time complexity.

The following batch program will demonstrate this task with both numbers and letters.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set max=0
for %%A in (1,2,99,3,4) do (
  set n=%%A
  if !n! GTR !max! set max=!n!
)
echo Greatest number: %max%

set max=0
for %%A in (A,C,B,Z,G) do (
  set n=%%A
  if !n! GTR !max! set max=!n!
)
echo Greatest letter: %max%
```

Comment: what's the point of `(11,1,2,3,10)` ?only 11,1 and 2 will be taken into account.

Comment: Sorry, seems I posted some old code that I'd played with at some point. I'll fix it now.

Comment: I've edited the code, using comma separated lists, to better demonstrate the theory presented.

Comment: Although your answer was quicker, Aacini's answer was more relevant to my situation. +1